# Foreign key constraint error on create

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I get the following error when trying to add a new item to a Kendo UI grid, specifically on the *SaveChanges* event:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Items_dbo.Categories_CategoryId". The conflict occurred in database "appdb", table "dbo.Categories", column 'CategoryId'
```

This is the code I'm using to add new items:

```
public int CreateItem(ItemViewModel viewModel)
{
     var item = new Item();
     viewModel.CopyToItem(item);

     db.Items.Add(item);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return item.ItemId;
}
```

*Item* viewmodel:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ItemId { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public int CategoryId { get; set; }

public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

public void CopyToItem(Item item)
{
    item.ItemId = this.ItemId;
    item.Description = this.Description;
    item.CategoryId = this.CategoryId;
}
```

*Category* model:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int CategoryId { get; set; }
public string CategoryName { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think error has no connection with kendo

Comment: Basically, the `CategoryID` you are adding for your new item doesn't exist in the `Categories` table. As it is a foreign key, it must exist.

Comment: @Neel - I’ve removed the reference to Kendo UI, thanks for pointing that out.

The ‘Categories’ table does contain the ‘CategoryId’ column and corresponding values do exist.

Comment: Debug your code. Chances are high that the item you're trying to save has the incorrect CategoryId since the error specifically tells you this is the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll go through my code. Could be a null value being passed from the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a problem with the Kendo grid code in the View. I was targeting *Category* as a column instead of *CategoryId*. My bad, should have been more observant. Thanks for the suggestions and for taking a look at my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set CategoryId to a valid value. Is CategoryId in the ViewModel?

Comment: Yes it is, as shown in the ViewModel code posted in my question.